# JS Multiple Choice Game can't detect the right answer

Tags: javascript

I am building this multiple choice game in JavaScript. The rules are fairly simple; the user gets asked what number1 + number2 equals, and there 4 different answers to pick (one is correct).

However, for some reason in my code, no matter what answer I pick (even if it's wrong), the game always tells me that I picked the right one.

Here is my code:

```
var num1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 10);
var num2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 10);
var result = num1 + num2;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    document.getElementById('field1').innerHTML = num1;
    document.getElementById('field2').innerHTML = num2;
    var opts = [];
    for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
      opts.push(findRandom(result,opts));
    }  
    opts.push(result);
    opts.sort();  
    for(var i=1;i<5;i++){ 
     document.getElementById('option'+i).innerHTML = opts[i-1];
    }  
  console.log(opts);
});

function findRandom(n,opts){
  var result = 0;
  while(result !=n && result == 0){
    result = Math.floor(Math.random() * (n + 1)); 
    if(opts.indexOf(result) >0){
      result = 0;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

var choices = document.querySelectorAll('.field-block');
[].slice.call(choices).forEach(function(choice){
   choice.addEventListener('click', function(){
      getChoice(choice);
   });
});

function getChoice(){
  if(choices.innerHTML = result){
    after.classList.remove('hide');
    after.classList.add('correct');
    after.innerHTML = 'Good job :) !';
  } else{
    after.classList.remove('hide');
    after.classList.add('wrong');
    after.innerHTML = "Wrong answer :( Try again !";
  }
}
```

Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/teenicarus/pen/Oxaaoe

Try it yourself, you will see the problem right away.

How do I fix this ?

I appreciate all responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of problems. Firstly you need to use the argument that's passed to the `getChoice()` function as it contains the selected `choice`. `choices` is *an array* of the available options.

Secondly, `=` is for value assignment. This is why you always had a successful result. You need to use `==` or `===` when *comparing* values. Try this:

```js
var num1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 10);
var num2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 10);
var result = num1 + num2;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  document.getElementById('field1').innerHTML = num1;
  document.getElementById('field2').innerHTML = num2;
  var opts = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    opts.push(findRandom(result, opts));
  }
  opts.push(result);
  opts.sort();
  for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    document.getElementById('option' + i).innerHTML = opts[i - 1];
  }
});

function findRandom(n, opts) {
  var result = 0;
  while (result != n && result == 0) {
    result = Math.floor(Math.random() * (n + 1));
    if (opts.indexOf(result) > 0) {
      result = 0;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

var choices = document.querySelectorAll('.field-block');
[].slice.call(choices).forEach(function(choice) {
  choice.addEventListener('click', function() {
    getChoice(choice);
  });
});

function getChoice(choice) {
  if (choice.innerHTML == result) {
    after.classList.remove('hide');
    after.classList.add('correct');
    after.innerHTML = 'Good job :) !';
  } else {
    after.classList.remove('hide');
    after.classList.add('wrong');
    after.innerHTML = "Wrong answer :( Try again !";
  }
}
```

```css
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-logo {
  animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  height: 60px;
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #222;
  height: 180px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.App-intro {
  font-size: large;
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.text-info {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2.1rem;
}

.question {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.options {
  margin: 5%;
  display: flex;
  margin-right: -12px;
  margin-left: -12px;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.fields {
  display: flex;
  padding: 12px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex: 1;
}

.field-block {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 160px;
  padding: 10%;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /*flex: 1 0 auto;*/
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f9bad0;
  font-size: 6rem;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.quiz {
  color: #ddd;
  margin: 2%;
  background-color: #ec1561;
  padding: 2%;
  width: 90%;
  position: relative;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  height: 48px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #2fcaaa;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .05), 0 2px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  transition: box-shadow 200ms ease-out;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.quiz .after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  height: 80%;
  /*display: none;*/
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  opacity: 0.8;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.correct {
  background-color: green;
}

.wrong {
  background-color: #D91E18;
}

.hide {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">

<a href="https://happy-learning.herokuapp.com/ " target="_blank"><img alt="Join Slack" height="40" width="139" src="http://i.imgur.com/0Lne5Vr.png" /></a>
<div>
  <h1>Adding Game</h1>
  <p id="demo">In this lecture, we will cover the game to add 2 numbers.</p>
</div>
<hr>

<div class="quiz">
  <div class="quiz-content">
    <div class="question">
      What is the sum of <span class="text-info" id="field1">5</span> and <span class="text-info" id="field2">5</span>?
    </div>
    <div class="options">
      <div class="fields animated zoomIn">
        <div class="field-block" id='option1'>
          <li>10</li>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="fields animated zoomIn">
        <div class="field-block" id="option2">
          <li>10</li>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="fields animated zoomIn">
        <div class="field-block" id="option3">
          <li>10</li>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="fields animated zoomIn">
        <div class="field-block" id="option4">
          <li>10</li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="after hide" id="after">

    </div>
    <div class="play-again">
      <a class="button" onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href">Play Again</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't fully gone through the example, but it's probably this:

```
if(choices.innerHTML = result){
```

You're assigning the result instead of testing it, so the outcome is always true.

Also you're not passing in choices:

```
function getChoice(){
```

Try

```
function getChoice(choices){
```

Answer (score 0):

You got two mistakes in there.
First: you're calling `getChoice()` in your eventhandler with param, but your function does not accept any param. 
Second: in your getChoice you're not comparing, you're assigning (= is not ==).

i fixed up your codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mBvpvb